# Python Scrape Financial Data From iFrame

Tags: python, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, phantomjs, forex

I'm trying to scrape data within the iFrame.

I have tried webdriver in Chrome as well as PhantomJS with no success. There are source links contained within the iframe where I assume its data is being pulled from, however, when using these links an error is generated saying "You can't render widget content without a correct InstanceId parameter."

Is it possible to access this data using python (PhantomJS)?

Comment: consider adding the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to network tools in your browser and investigate what data go to the server and just scrape via simple requests.